# how to add items to the toolbar spinner dynamically in android

Tags: java, android

I created a simple spinner in tool bar with items in string, I don't need this items in string.xml,I just want add Item through java code
I just want to add items to tool bar spinner dynamically as these item taken from data base in a selects form and this is my Activity code

```
package abtech.waiteriano.com.actionbartest;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;
    private String[] category = {"hello", "this", "is", "me"};

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        category = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category);
        toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
//        toolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.category, R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
        Spinner navigationSpinner = new Spinner(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
        navigationSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        toolbar.addView(navigationSpinner, 0);
        navigationSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "you selected: " + category[position],
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add your array of string directly into to ArrayAdapter like below :

```
private String[] category = {"hello", "this", "is", "me"};

Spinner navigationSpinner = new Spinner(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, category);
navigationSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I have the same problem here It shows only the item that it was in string.xml not in the private String[] category = {"hello", "this", "is", "me"};

Comment: Sorry I edit some thing now it works well thanks alot